# Is there any way to make an anti-aliased circle in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, draw

I'm trying to draw a circle in a picture using open CV with Python.

Here is the picture I wish I can make :

[image]

Here is the code I write :

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
import imutils

text1 = "10x"  
text2 = "20gr"  

# Load image in OpenCV  
image = cv2.imread('Sasa.jfif')
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
cv2.circle(resized,(350,150),65,(102,51,17),thickness=-1)

# Convert the image to RGB (OpenCV uses BGR)  
cv2_im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  

# Pass the image to PIL  
pil_im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im_rgb)  

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im)  
# use a truetype font  
font1 = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 50)  
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 25)  

# Draw the text  
draw.text((310,110), text1, font=font1) 
draw.text((325,170), text2, font=font2) 

# Get back the image to OpenCV  
cv2_im_processed = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_im), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  

cv2.imshow('Fonts', cv2_im_processed)  
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

But this is what my code generate :

[image]

The circle line is not precise. Is there anything I can do to make the line preciser or is there any other library that generates circle with precise line ?

Any suggestion will be very appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use anti aliasing to make the circle look better as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html):

```
cv2.circle(resized,(350,150),65,(102,51,17),thickness=-1,lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```